Phalasruti of Sri Saraswati ashtakam
What are the phalasruti of the Saraswati ashtakam written in Padma puran ?

The Saraswati Ashtakam of Padma Purana was composed by Deva Guru Brihaspati and can be found here.
Brihaspati himself mentions the fruits of reciting it as follows:

Bruhaspathir Uvacha:
The Guru of devas told:-
Yadhi may Varada   Devi  jnanam   sidham  prayascha na  .
If you are pleased me oh Goddess  , wont you grant me wisdom and
divine powers.
11.Hantha  they nirmala jnanam  , kumathi dwamsa  karanam,
Stotrenanena   ye  bhakthya   sthuvanthi   maneshina
To those men  who pray     using this prayer with devotion,
I would   grant them pure knowledge   and destroy wicked knowledge.
12.Labanthe paramam jnanam , yath parairapi   durlabham,
Prapnothi   purusho  nithyam  Mahamaya  prasadatha.
Due  to the grace of the great enchantress  people   would  get divine
knowledge,
And also daily get   the     divinity , which  is difficult to
achieve.
13.Trisandhyam   prayatho nithyam   padeth ashtakamuthamam,
Thasye kande   sadaa  vaasam   karishyaami na samsaya.
If this great octet   prayer   is chanted daily at dawn, noon and dusk
I would always live in  his throat   and there  is no doubt   about
it.
Ithi   Sri Padma purane   Sri SAravasthyashtakam,
This is the octet on Goddess  Saraswathi     from Padma Purana.

